# Connection timed out call from external source

Tags: docker, nginx

I have the following nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    server_tokens off;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name _;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://example.org;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

I am running nginx in a docker container and it starts properly. When I execute: curl localhost I receive `301 Moved Permanently`. But when I try to call from an external source `curl publicIP` I receive `Timed out`

My first thought was that the problem is from the firewall but if I start a nginx container without any configuration `curl publicIP` works properly I receive 200.

Can you help me figure out if it's a problem in nginx configuration?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that your https queries (**"proxy_pass  http:// example.org"**) do not end up at your port 80 ( which redirects back to 443 )? Should not address in proxy_pass be kind of http://localhost:someport or address of another VPS/VM/container, i.e.: _proxy_pass http:// my-upstream-server;_?